# Bizarre Object Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Windows Service with a log file to write any exceptions caught. In a simple foreach using LINQ, I am getting an exception for the classic:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

However, when I run the code locally, by 'freezing' the Windows Service code and just running the code through a Main function, I can't seem to replicate this issue. The stack trace says the line causing the issue is 142.

```
var newTickets = tickets
    .Where(t => t != null)
    .Where(t => (DateTime)t.LastActivityDate >= lastAutoTaskSync); 

foreach(Ticket ticket in newTickets) //Line 142
```

Strangely, I have checked everything possible I could think it could be, by adding the following lines:

```
var newTickets = tickets
    .Where(t => t != null)
    .Where(t => (DateTime)t.LastActivityDate >= lastAutoTaskSync);

if (newTickets == null) throw new Exception("newTickets is null");
if (tickets == null) throw new Exception("tickets is null");
if (lastAutoTaskSync == null) throw new Exception("date is null");

foreach (Ticket ticket in newTickets)
```

And again, the same line throws the same exception.

Is there anything that I may be missing, or something that could cause this exception? I thought it may be the code inside the LINQ, such as `LastActivityDate` being null, but if that were the case, surely this would be the line to throw the exception, not the foreach itself?

To add, the code runs around 50% of the time, running through the `foreach` with no issues. For example, the service log indicates that the code in the loop runs 3 or 4 times, and then the exception hits on the fifth.

Comment: Remember that IEnumerable isn't evaluated until you start using it. My guess, `t.LastActivityDate` is `null` in the first element of the array.

You could check this by adding a `.ToList()` to `var newTickets` and see if the error moves there.

Comment: Is your code optimised? If so, the line number from the exception details may be incorrect.

Comment: @JeffFoster: if `LastActivityDate` is a nullable DateTime and some are null he'd get a `System.InvalidOperationException` instead on the cast to `DateTime`.

Comment: What is `tickets`? Is this an `IQueryable` that itself executes some other lambdas that may cause the exception?

Comment: @codran The line numbers are reporting correctly yeah. I threw an exception above all this to double check, and they're reporting correctly.

@JeffFoster As Tim said, I was relying on the cast to pick up on this. All properties on the object are `object` type. I have added a `.ToList()` and have put it back on the test server.

It may be worth noting that this code runs half the time with no issues and performs the functions coded into it.

Comment: @plusheen: even if it can't cause this issue you should remember how LINQ works. Most methods are using deferred execution, that means they are not executed immediately. That's why you notice the exception at the `foreach` which will execute the query (`Any`, `First`, `ToList`,`ToArray` are other methods that would execute the query). But as mentioned before, you'd get an `InvalidOperationException` if a date would be `null` because you can't cast it to `DateTime` then([`Nullable<T>.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx) is called).

Comment: @plusheen: so you should change the code: `.Where(t => t.LastActivityDate.HasValue &&  t.LastActivityDate >= lastAutoTaskSync);`

Comment: I'll try again: What is _tickets_?! Is this already enumerated or are there other lambdas that are executed only at the foreach but are not shown in this question already?

Comment: Sorry @RenéVogt , tickets is type `List<Ticket>`, where ticket is a simple model with several `object` type properties, populated by a web service. When retrieving tickets, if none were found, `tickets` is an empty, but instantiated `List<Ticket>`. 

@TimSchmelter I have converted the datetime to a nullable, and checked for a value. So far, it hasn't fallen over yet. I'll give it 10-20 mins to cycle a few more times and cross my fingers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter With the nullable DateTime value checking, and `ToList()` called on the LINQ query itself rather than letting the `foreach` evaluate it, the exception popped up again, still on line 142.

Comment: @plusheen: as mentioned,i would have  been surprised because a `NullReferncreException` is not an `InvalidOperationException`. But if you use `ToList` before the `foreach` and that doesn't cause an exception it seems as if the line number is not correct. The `ToList` should cause the same exception as the `foreach` but on a different line.

Comment: Can you verify that `tickets` is not null? Do a null check before the linq statements, not after.

Comment: Bizarre or not, it's just a NRE and should be processed as such. If you can't debug (or duplicate during debugging), then provide/look at the exception call stack (or `exception.ToString()` output)

Comment: Weirdly, it seems that even despite optimising the code and checking line numbers with other exception throws, the line numbers did go out of sync as mentioned by @codran. The exception was actually further within the foreach loop. The stack trace reporting incorrect line numbers threw me off entirely, and I didn't even look that far. Apologies for the wild goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace was reporting a wrong line number, causing me to believe the LINQ query was causing the exception. In reality, the exception was being thrown within the foreach loop, a few lines down, where I try to access an object within a `Ticket`'s properties, which was null.

Lesson learned, don't always believe in and rely on the stack trace entirely!